# SQLite How to handle Negative numbers with Negative Sign at the end

Tags: sqlite, negative-number

We've never experienced this before. We are importing Tab Delimited TXT files that include numeric columns. Negative numbers have the indicator behind the number and not in front (e.g. 550.00- rather than -550.00).

We are using SQLite Expert Professional. When reviewing the import results in the table, any number with the negative sign in the back was converted to the negative sign in the front but everyone of these cells are highlighted in blue (we are not sure why SQLite Expert is doing this but assume it has meaning). In addition, when querying and summing they are being ignored causing the resulting value to be higher than expected.

The field types are FLOAT and DECIMAL

We have googled and cannot find any results about negative sign location.

Appreciate any assistance on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE query could alter the values by subtracting the incorrect value from 0 after replacing the negative sign with nothing.

The UPDATE could be based upon :-

```
UPDATE vneg SET iv = (0 - replace(iv,'-','')) WHERE instr(iv,'-') > 1;
```

e.g. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vneg;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vneg (iv);
INSERT INTO vneg VALUES ('100.35'),('133.44-'),('25.453-');
SELECT * FROM vneg; -- First Result (before)
UPDATE vneg SET iv = (0 - replace(iv,'-','')) WHERE instr(iv,'-') > 1;
SELECT * FROM vneg; -- Second result (after)
```

Before the update :-

[image]

After the Update :-

[image]

And then using `SELECT sum(iv) AS summed FROM vneg;` results in :-

**-58.543**